# Can I trust in "%" to be the SQL wildcard

Tags: sql, jpa

Hi there I'm using JPA to query a database and I should do a `column like 'whatever%'` query.

My DB is currently Mysql so I could do that without problem, but I was wondering if there was somewhere a method to retrieve the Wildcard character of the database.

There's little chance I change the DB but well ... I'm trying to be as generic as possible.

So is "%" the only wildcard (not talking about `_`) used, and will forever be ?

Thanks for info!

Comment: How on earth would you expect us to guarantee that the year 2618 version of SQL doesn't use another character?

Comment: That's the point, do you know any way to ask the DB for it ?

Comment: Are you really worried about your app lasting longer than the SQL standard?

Comment: Not worried, I'm a lot optimistic ! Apart from future, what if my client decides to change the DB ?

Comment: What is the syntax `like column='whatever%'` query?  Do you mean `column like 'whatever%'`?  The first is not normal syntax.  The second is standard, including the wildcard.

Comment: If you client changes databases, wildcard is least of your problem.

Comment: Not finding that it's referenced as part of the standard JPA documentation.  So you'd have to worry about JPA, too....

Comment: @GordonLinoff Corrected the mistyped example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` is ANSI SQL.  This value isn't configurable in any of the major databases, and as such there is no need for these databases to provide a method to return the wildcard character.

This should only be a concern if you think you might migrate to a non-ANSI SQL database, such as MS Access, which uses a `*` as a wildcard character.

If is is a possibility, I'd suggest making the wildcard character configurable in your application, and provide a variable containing the wildcard character instead of a hard-coded character.

Comment: I use adapters for the various databases anyway as queries have minor differences in syntax. Using this method would also give me the opportunity to handcraft the LIKE operator (and eventually use full text search capabilites as well)